# Data Mining Classification on transactional data - which algorithmn fits best?

Tags: transactions, classification, data-mining

i have transactional database - the data looks as follows:

> **ID - COLUMN1 - COLUMN2 - COLUMN3**
>
> 0 - **A** - B - C
>
> 0 - A - **D** - C
>
> 0 - E - B - **C**
>
> 1 - A - B - C
>
> 1 - A - B - C
>
> 2 - **A** - **D** - C
>
> 2 - A - B - **F**
>
> 3 - A - D - C
>
> 3 - **A** - **B** - **F**
>
> 3 - A - B - C

Now i want to use a classification algorithmn to classify fraud:

> **ID - CLASSIFICATION**
>
> 0 - critical (because of the pattern "A D C")
>
> 1 - uncritical (no conspicuous pattern detected)
>
> 2 - critical (A D F)
>
> 3 - critical (A B F)

The patterns can occur on only one row or more rows. 1 Transaction contains multiple rows (-> ID).

Which algorithmn fits best or which algorithmns comes in question?

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm you need is called

### if-then-else statements.

You have predefined rules, they are best encoded using code.